# Can I make a list of mail senders in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Can I make a list of people who send me mail in gmail? 
If so, How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Scripts](http://www.labnol.org/internet/extract-gmail-addresses/28037/) to extract email addresses from Gmail.